# Table name is a keyword in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm using SQL queries in Python Django project. I have already created database in SQL Server.

In python we need to write SQL queries in quotation marks like, `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Table")`. In my case table name is a keyword `Order`. So, now when I try to use double quote mark `""` it give error on Order  `"SELECT * FROM 'Order'"` because table name should be in double quotation marks.

When I use single quote mark `''` it gives error on condition. `'SELECT * FROM "Order" WHERE paymentsID = "TW-MO14"'` because condition should have in
single quote.

Is there any solution?

Comment: The delimit identifiers  for objects in T-SQL are brackets (`[]`), which are specific to T-SQL, and double quotes (`"`), which are the ANSI identifier. Single quotes (`'`) are for literal strings, not objects; this means `paymentsID = "TW-MO14"` would be comparing the column `paymentsID` to the **column** `TW-MO14`. Though *really* you should rename your object to *not* be a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Also, `ORDER` isn't just a (reserved) keyword in T-SQL; it's a (reserved) keyword in SQL in general. Any dialect will very likely require the word `ORDER` delimit identified unless it is being used in the place it is supposed to be; in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. Yes the mistake was made by the developer who made the database.
I found one solution that we can write the queries in parts by concatenating the string. And it is working.
`'SELECT * FROM "Order" WHERE' + " paymentsID = 'TW-MO14'"`

Comment: I would have, personally, gone with `"SELECT * FROM dbo.[Order] WHERE paymentID = 'TW-MO14';"` Or, as I suggested, `EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.[Order]', N'CustomerOrder', N'TABLE';` (though obviously `CustomerOrder` might not be the most appropriate name), and then you can just do `"SELECT * FROM dbo.CustomerOrder WHERE paymentID = 'TW-MO14';"`

Comment: Will this permanently change the name from `Order` to `CustomerOrder`?
Or we can use the older name?

Comment: `sys.sp_rename` *renames* the object. As I mentioned in my [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724351/table-name-is-a-keyword-in-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment121454930_68724351) what you should *really* be doing is renaming the object to *not* be a reserved keyword.

Comment: The database is provided by the client. I cant change anything. I just have to work on it.

Comment: You want `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM [Order] WHERE paymentsID = 'TW-MO14';")`